# Individual Email Sends in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have installed the Marketing Cloud Connector for Salesforce, but now we want to see the Individual send results per contact in Salesforce. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

How are you performing your sends? 
If the connector is correctly installed then the data should be passed back to Salesforce, however, you need to ensure you're using the correct Contact Key / Subscriber Key to ensure tracking is passed back accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have setup connector, please make sure you are updating the page layouts to include "Individual Email Results (IER)" related list to Contacts.

Also when you set up the tracking within Marketing Cloud connector(screen in salesforce crm as soon as you connect to Marketing Cloud), select the option "Individual Level Tracking". you can confirm this by Navigating to Marketing Cloud Tab > Click on "Configure Marketing Cloud Connector" Link as shown below.

[image]

Please make sure you have selected Individual Level Tracking.

[image]

If you are initiating Email Send (Via EMail Send tab in salesforce crm) to a campaign or report, it does get updated to the Contact Related List IER automatically.

If you are sending emails via Marketing Cloud (Journey Builder or Content Builder), make sure you select the option "Send Tracking Data to Sales Cloud" checkbox. The tracking results will be populated under salesforce Contact related list"IER". This is assuming your subscribers in Marketing CLoud is using 18 digit salesforce contact id as Subscriber Key.

Please note: you can set the tracking interval within Marketing Cloud connector (typically hourly) and hence there will be a delay in getting IER populated in salesforce crm.

Also, IER will have an impact on your data storage in salesforce crm.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Also make sure that the API user(a specific user) in Marketing Cloud is integrated with the Salesforce user (System user or API user) . Because this helps in sending tracking data to Sales cloud.